# Can't run compiled cpp code with armadillo, because of dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: c++, armadillo

I followed the installation instructions (Mac OS) here:

https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/#5-linux-and-macos-installation

I successfully compiled the example code, as given here:

http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#example_prog

by

```
g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -larmadillo
```

then I tried to run the output, but got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libhdf5.101.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.9.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514783/what-is-the-exact-equivalent-to-ld-preload-on-osx

Answer (score 0):

You need the `-rpath` linker option when building your application to tell the loader where to look for that library.

Usually a Mac application is it’s own folder tree known as a bundle. In there, you would put your library file and then list `@executable_path/relative_path_to_library` in your application binary as a place to look when the loader sees `@rpath`.

Further reading:
[Run-Path Dependent Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error with Armadillo. What I did was first uninstall Armadillo (this might not be necessary). Then I did `brew install armadillo --with-hdf5`. Since this is a linking issue (Armadillo is looking for `libhdf5.101.dylib` in the wrong place) I next did `brew link armadillo`. Then if you get a conflicting file error, just do `brew link --overwrite armadillo`. Good luck!