# R package with Fortran code (write problem)

Tags: r, fortran

I built an R-package with several Fortran subroutines back in 2012. Up to 2019 (or a bit earlier)  I had no problem updating and running the package under an R session.  The Fortran source has a lot of write and format. Prior to 2019, the output of these commands showed up nicely on the screen (RStudio or Rconsole), but after that the same commands break R (and RStudio) with R (3.6.3), clang (12.0.0) and gfortran (11.2.0) on macOS Catalina

```
> res=olsml65(model,x,y,10) [1] 0 Into Fortran code  
nst =            2  
leng =         1114   
*** caught segfault *** 
address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'
Traceback:  1: olsml65(model, x, y, 10) 
Possible actions: 
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled) 
2: normal R exit 
3: exit R without saving workspace 
4: exit R saving workspace
```

If I use print instead of write and no format at all, the package runs smoothly.

Here is one line that breaks R:

```
    write(6,999) j
999   format(' * (Process) terms of submodel',i2,' under regression *')
```

I could get rid of all writes but I wonder if there is a workaround.

Comment: How exactly does it break? Does `print 999,j` break it? Does `write (*,*) j` break it? Does `write(6,*) j` break it? Does `write(*,999) j` break it? Does Is unit `6` opened anywhere?

Comment: print 999, write(6,999) and write(*,999) break it.  Format seems to be the problem. Unit 6 opens the display in R console or RStudio.

Example:  
> res=olsml65(model,x,y,10)
[1] 0
Into Fortran code
 nst =            2  leng =         1114

Comment: And what about `write (*,*) ' * (Process) terms of submodel',j,' under regression *')'`? What exactly happens? Does it crash? Is there any error message? Which gfortran do you use? Does R does with its own gfortran? Which OS?

Comment: It works just fine.    No error msg, nothing. Only  the output on the screen:   * terms of submodel           2  under regression *        1114

Comment: So I do not understand the problem. What should happen instead?

Comment: I don't use write(6,*)  but write with a format for a nice display of the results.  Format breaks R.   Can an external C function do the job?

Comment: Bot **how** does it break R? What should happen instead? Please also add the compiler and OS versions into your question.

Comment: R (3.6.3), clang (12.0.0) and gfortran (11.2.0) on macOS Catalina.  

It breaks R when it reaches

write(6,239) nst, leng
239    format(' * terms of submodel',i3,' under regression *',i4)

Here is what I see on an R session: 

> res=olsml65(model,x,y,10)
[1] 0
Into Fortran code
 nst =            2  leng =         1114

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: olsml65(model, x, y, 10)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace

Comment: Are there any other versions of *libgfortran* anywhere on your computer? Please check the formatting inside the edited question. The error messages and other important information really belong there.

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few versions of the library.

Comment: It is very likely some kind of clash between these versions.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you know how to remove them safely?

Comment: No. I would try to find which one (if any at all) works better using https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515047/721644

Comment: Thanks.  Somehow I don't think that will be the problem.   If I am not mistaken, I think I heard that there is an issue with fortran-write.

Comment: That is very unlikely.

Comment: Many thanks.  One last question. clang (mac) is called to link the libraries.  Unfortunately, clang is using an old library (-L option).  How can I change that?  Sorry but it has been a long time since I work with that.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you ever so much!   I managed to remember how to change the settings (not in a clear but it worked).  You were completely right.  The problem was a mixed-up library.